# Conditional Logic on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How to apply conditional logic to a Pandas DataFrame.

See DataFrame shown below,

```
   data desired_output
0     1          False
1     2          False
2     3           True
3     4           True
```

My original data is show in the 'data' column and the desired_output is shown next to it. If the number in 'data' is below 2.5, the desired_output is False.

I could apply a loop and do re-construct the DataFrame... but that would be 'un-pythonic'

Comment: maybe I don't know pandas, but it seems that you have *two* numbers in `data` -- which one are you checking against (seemingly the one on the right? What relevance is the number on the left?)

Comment: the number on the left is the index and the one on the right is the data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just compare the column with that value:

```
In [9]: df = pandas.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns=["data"])

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
   data
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4

In [11]: df["desired"] = df["data"] > 2.5
In [11]: df
Out[12]: 
   data desired
0     1   False
1     2   False
2     3    True
3     4    True
```

Answer (score 76):

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   data
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
```

You want to apply a function that conditionally returns a value based on the selected dataframe column.

```
In [2]: df['data'].apply(lambda x: 'true' if x <= 2.5 else 'false')
Out[2]:
0     true
1     true
2    false
3    false
Name: data
```

You can then assign that returned column to a new column in your dataframe:

```
In [3]: df['desired_output'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: 'true' if x <= 2.5 else 'false')

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   data desired_output
0     1           true
1     2           true
2     3          false
3     4          false
```

Comment: Although this answer is more verbose and not as simple as the answer @Jasc gave, it is more general and can be applied to other situations in which one wants output other than true and false.

Comment: `apply` + `lambda` is not recommended for easily vectorisable operations. Use `np.where` or `loc` methods instead to utilize Pandas / NumPy vectorisation.

Answer (score 18):

```
In [34]: import pandas as pd

In [35]: import numpy as np

In [36]:  df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns=["data"])

In [37]: df
Out[37]: 
   data
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4

In [38]: df["desired_output"] = np.where(df["data"] <2.5, "False", "True")

In [39]: df
Out[39]: 
   data desired_output
0     1          False
1     2          False
2     3           True
3     4           True
```

Comment: This is good, but the < seems unnecessarily confusing. If the condition is true, the first value results, if false the second value results. So it seems far more clear (and equivalent) to have the right side = np.where(df["data"] >= 2.5, "True", "False")

Answer (score 15):

In this specific example, where the DataFrame is only one column, you can write this elegantly as:

```
df['desired_output'] = df.le(2.5)
```

*`le` tests whether elements are less than or equal 2.5, similarly `lt` for less than, `gt` and `ge`.*

Comment: OP wants to return *False* if `df['data'] < 2.5`. So you should use `gt` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) here:

```
In [3]: df.eval('desired_output = data >= 2.5', inplace=True)

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   data  desired_output
0     1           False
1     2           False
2     3            True
3     4            True
```

Since `inplace=True` you don't need to assign it back to `df`.