# How do I create a new column where the values are selected based on existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

How do I add a `color` column to the following dataframe so that `color='green'` if `Set == 'Z'`, and `color='red'` otherwise?

```
   Type  Set
1     A    Z
2     B    Z           
3     B    X
4     C    Y
```

Comment: Related: [Create new column based on values from other columns / apply a function of multiple columns, row-wise in Pandas](/q/26886653/4518341) (same idea, but the selection criteria are based on multiple columns)

Comment: Since pandas 2.2.0, you can use `case_when` (a syntax useful in SQL in the context in the OP). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73619829/19123103) for a demo.

Answer (score 1046, accepted):

**If you only have two choices to select from then use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):**

```
df['color'] = np.where(df['Set']=='Z', 'green', 'red')
```

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABBC'), 'Set':list('ZZXY')})
df['color'] = np.where(df['Set']=='Z', 'green', 'red')
print(df)
```

yields

```
  Set Type  color
0   Z    A  green
1   Z    B  green
2   X    B    red
3   Y    C    red
```

---

**If you have more than two conditions then use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)**. For example, if you want `color` to be

- `yellow` when `(df['Set'] == 'Z') & (df['Type'] == 'A')`
- otherwise `blue` when `(df['Set'] == 'Z') & (df['Type'] == 'B')`
- otherwise `purple` when `(df['Type'] == 'B')`
- otherwise `black`,

then use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABBC'), 'Set':list('ZZXY')})
conditions = [
    (df['Set'] == 'Z') & (df['Type'] == 'A'),
    (df['Set'] == 'Z') & (df['Type'] == 'B'),
    (df['Type'] == 'B')]
choices = ['yellow', 'blue', 'purple']
df['color'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='black')
print(df)
```

which yields

```
  Set Type   color
0   Z    A  yellow
1   Z    B    blue
2   X    B  purple
3   Y    C   black
```

Answer (score 185):

List comprehension is another way to create another column conditionally. If you are working with object dtypes in columns, like in your example, list comprehensions typically outperform most other methods.

Example list comprehension:

```
df['color'] = ['red' if x == 'Z' else 'green' for x in df['Set']]
```

**%timeit tests:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABBC'), 'Set':list('ZZXY')})
%timeit df['color'] = ['red' if x == 'Z' else 'green' for x in df['Set']]
%timeit df['color'] = np.where(df['Set']=='Z', 'green', 'red')
%timeit df['color'] = df.Set.map( lambda x: 'red' if x == 'Z' else 'green')

1000 loops, best of 3: 239 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 523 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 263 µs per loop
```

Comment: Note that, with much larger dataframes (think `pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABBC')*100000, 'Set':list('ZZXY')*100000})`-size), `numpy.where` outpaces `map`, but the list comprehension is king (about 50% faster than `numpy.where`).

Comment: Can the list comprehension method be used if the condition needs information from multiple columns? I am looking for something like this (this does not work): `df['color'] = ['red' if (x['Set'] == 'Z') & (x['Type'] == 'B') else 'green' for x in df]`

Comment: Add iterrows to the dataframe, then you can access multiple columns via row:

['red' if (row['Set'] == 'Z') & (row['Type'] == 'B') else 'green' for index, row in in df.iterrows()]

Comment: Note this nice solution will not work if you need to take replacement values from another series in the data frame, such as `df['color_type'] = np.where(df['Set']=='Z', 'green', df['Type'])`

Comment: @cheekybastard Or don't, since `.iterrows()` is notoriously sluggish and the DataFrame shouldn't be modified while iterating.

Comment: For me, df['color'] = ['red' if x == 'Z' else 'green' for x in df['Set']]
 is working.

Answer (score 30):

The following is slower than the approaches timed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31173785/1878788), but we can compute the extra column based on the contents of more than one column, and more than two values can be computed for the extra column.

Simple example using just the "Set" column:

```
def set_color(row):
    if row["Set"] == "Z":
        return "red"
    else:
        return "green"

df = df.assign(color=df.apply(set_color, axis=1))

print(df)
```

```
  Set Type  color
0   Z    A    red
1   Z    B    red
2   X    B  green
3   Y    C  green
```

Example with more colours and more columns taken into account:

```
def set_color(row):
    if row["Set"] == "Z":
        return "red"
    elif row["Type"] == "C":
        return "blue"
    else:
        return "green"

df = df.assign(color=df.apply(set_color, axis=1))

print(df)
```

```
  Set Type  color
0   Z    A    red
1   Z    B    red
2   X    B  green
3   Y    C   blue
```

#### Edit (21/06/2019): Using plydata

It is also possible to use [plydata](https://github.com/has2k1/plydata) to do this kind of things (this seems even slower than using `assign` and `apply`, though).

```
from plydata import define, if_else
```

Simple `if_else`:

```
df = define(df, color=if_else('Set=="Z"', '"red"', '"green"'))

print(df)
```

```
  Set Type  color
0   Z    A    red
1   Z    B    red
2   X    B  green
3   Y    C  green
```

Nested `if_else`:

```
df = define(df, color=if_else(
    'Set=="Z"',
    '"red"',
    if_else('Type=="C"', '"green"', '"blue"')))

print(df)
```

```
  Set Type  color
0   Z    A    red
1   Z    B    red
2   X    B   blue
3   Y    C  green
```

Answer (score 28):

Another way in which this could be achieved is

```
df['color'] = df.Set.map( lambda x: 'red' if x == 'Z' else 'green')
```

Answer (score 26):

You can simply use the powerful `.loc` method and use one condition or several depending on your need (tested with pandas=1.0.5).

Code Summary:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(Type='A B B C'.split(), Set='Z Z X Y'.split()))
df['Color'] = "red"
df.loc[(df['Set']=="Z"), 'Color'] = "green"

#practice!
df.loc[(df['Set']=="Z")&(df['Type']=="B")|(df['Type']=="C"), 'Color'] = "purple"
```

Explanation:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(Type='A B B C'.split(), Set='Z Z X Y'.split()))

# df so far: 
  Type Set  
0    A   Z 
1    B   Z 
2    B   X 
3    C   Y
```

add a 'color' column and set all values to "red"

```
df['Color'] = "red"
```

Apply your single condition:

```
df.loc[(df['Set']=="Z"), 'Color'] = "green"


# df: 
  Type Set  Color
0    A   Z  green
1    B   Z  green
2    B   X    red
3    C   Y    red
```

or multiple conditions if you want:

```
df.loc[(df['Set']=="Z")&(df['Type']=="B")|(df['Type']=="C"), 'Color'] = "purple"
```

You can read on Pandas logical operators and conditional selection here:
[Logical operators for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas)

Answer (score 25):

Here's yet another way to skin this cat, using a dictionary to map new values onto the keys in the list:

```
def map_values(row, values_dict):
    return values_dict[row]

values_dict = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4}

df = pd.DataFrame({'INDICATOR': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'VALUE': [10, 9, 8, 7]})

df['NEW_VALUE'] = df['INDICATOR'].apply(map_values, args = (values_dict,))
```

What's it look like:

```
df
Out[2]: 
  INDICATOR  VALUE  NEW_VALUE
0         A     10          1
1         B      9          2
2         C      8          3
3         D      7          4
```

This approach can be very powerful when you have many `ifelse`-type statements to make (i.e. many unique values to replace).

And of course you could always do this:

```
df['NEW_VALUE'] = df['INDICATOR'].map(values_dict)
```

But that approach is more than three times as slow as the `apply` approach from above, on my machine.

And you could also do this, using `dict.get`:

```
df['NEW_VALUE'] = [values_dict.get(v, None) for v in df['INDICATOR']]
```

Comment: Update: On 100,000,000 rows, 52 string values, `.apply()` takes 47 seconds, versus only 5.91 seconds for `.map()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use pandas methods [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas.Series.where) and [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html#pandas.Series.mask):

```
df['color'] = 'green'
df['color'] = df['color'].where(df['Set']=='Z', other='red')
# Replace values where the condition is False
```

or

```
df['color'] = 'red'
df['color'] = df['color'].mask(df['Set']=='Z', other='green')
# Replace values where the condition is True
```

Alternatively, you can use the method `transform` with a lambda function:

```
df['color'] = df['Set'].transform(lambda x: 'green' if x == 'Z' else 'red')
```

Output:

```
  Type Set  color
1    A   Z  green
2    B   Z  green
3    B   X    red
4    C   Y    red
```

Performance comparison from @chai:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABBC')*1000000, 'Set':list('ZZXY')*1000000})
 
%timeit df['color1'] = 'red'; df['color1'].where(df['Set']=='Z','green')
%timeit df['color2'] = ['red' if x == 'Z' else 'green' for x in df['Set']]
%timeit df['color3'] = np.where(df['Set']=='Z', 'red', 'green')
%timeit df['color4'] = df.Set.map(lambda x: 'red' if x == 'Z' else 'green')

397 ms ± 101 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
976 ms ± 241 ms per loop
673 ms ± 139 ms per loop
796 ms ± 182 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have only **2 choices**, use `np.where()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(3)})
df['B'] = np.where(df.A>2, 'yes', 'no')
```

if you have over **2 choices**, maybe `apply()` could work
input

```
arr = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abc'), 'B':range(3), 'C':range(3,6), 'D':range(6, 9)})
```

and arr is

```
    A   B   C   D
0   a   0   3   6
1   b   1   4   7
2   c   2   5   8
```

if you want the column E tobe `if arr.A =='a' then arr.B elif arr.A=='b' then arr.C elif arr.A == 'c' then arr.D else something_else`

```
arr['E'] = arr.apply(lambda x: x['B'] if x['A']=='a' else(x['C'] if x['A']=='b' else(x['D'] if x['A']=='c' else 1234)), axis=1)
```

and finally the arr is

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   a   0   3   6   0
1   b   1   4   7   4
2   c   2   5   8   8
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner with `.apply()` method is following:

```
df['color'] = df['Set'].apply(lambda set_: 'green' if set_=='Z' else 'red')
```

After that, `df` data frame looks like this:

```
>>> print(df)
  Type Set  color
0    A   Z  green
1    B   Z  green
2    B   X    red
3    C   Y    red
```

Answer (score 2):

The [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.case_when.html#janitor.case_when) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/index.html) is a wrapper around `pd.Series.mask` and offers a chainable/convenient form for multiple conditions:

For a single condition:

```py
df.case_when(
    df.col1 == "Z",  # condition
    "green",         # value if True
    "red",           # value if False
    column_name = "color"
    )

  Type Set  color
1    A   Z  green
2    B   Z  green
3    B   X    red
4    C   Y    red
```

For multiple conditions:

```py
df.case_when(
    df.Set.eq('Z') & df.Type.eq('A'), 'yellow', # condition, result
    df.Set.eq('Z') & df.Type.eq('B'), 'blue',   # condition, result
    df.Type.eq('B'), 'purple',                  # condition, result
    'black',              # default if none of the conditions evaluate to True
    column_name = 'color'  
)
  Type  Set   color
1    A   Z  yellow
2    B   Z    blue
3    B   X  purple
4    C   Y   black
```

More examples can be found [here](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/blob/dev/examples/notebooks/case_when.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy **one-liner** you can use when you have **one or several conditions**:

```
df['color'] = np.select(condlist=[df['Set']=="Z", df['Set']=="Y"], choicelist=["green", "yellow"], default="red")
```

Easy and good to go!

See more here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html

Answer (score 0):

**If you're working with massive data, a memoized approach would be best:**

```
# First create a dictionary of manually stored values
color_dict = {'Z':'red'}

# Second, build a dictionary of "other" values
color_dict_other = {x:'green' for x in df['Set'].unique() if x not in color_dict.keys()}

# Next, merge the two
color_dict.update(color_dict_other)

# Finally, map it to your column
df['color'] = df['Set'].map(color_dict)
```

*This approach will be fastest when you have many repeated values.* My general rule of thumb is to memoize when: `data_size` > `10**4` & `n_distinct` < `data_size/4`

*E.x. Memoize in a case 10,000 rows with 2,500 or fewer distinct values.*

Comment: Alright, so with only 2 distinct values to map, 100,000,000 rows, it takes 6.67 seconds to run without "memoization", and 9.86 seconds with.

Comment: 100,000,000 rows, 52 distinct values, where 1 of those maps to the first output value, and the other 51 all correspond to the other: 7.99 seconds without memoization, 11.1 seconds with.

Comment: Are your values in random order? Or are they back to back? High speed of pandas could be due to caching @AMC

Comment: _Are your values in random order? Or are they back to back?_ Values are random, selected using `random.choices()`.

Answer (score 0):

A Less verbose approach using `np.select`:

```
a = np.array([['A','Z'],['B','Z'],['B','X'],['C','Y']])
df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['Type','Set'])

conditions = [
    df['Set'] == 'Z'
]

outputs = [
    'Green'
    ]
             # conditions Z is Green, Red Otherwise.
res = np.select(conditions, outputs, 'Red')
res 
array(['Green', 'Green', 'Red', 'Red'], dtype='<U5')
df.insert(2, 'new_column',res)    

df
    Type    Set new_column
0   A   Z   Green
1   B   Z   Green
2   B   X   Red
3   C   Y   Red

df.to_numpy()    
    
array([['A', 'Z', 'Green'],
       ['B', 'Z', 'Green'],
       ['B', 'X', 'Red'],
       ['C', 'Y', 'Red']], dtype=object)

%%timeit conditions = [df['Set'] == 'Z'] 
outputs = ['Green'] 
np.select(conditions, outputs, 'Red')

134 µs ± 9.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABBC')*1000000, 'Set':list('ZZXY')*1000000})
%%timeit conditions = [df2['Set'] == 'Z'] 
outputs = ['Green'] 
np.select(conditions, outputs, 'Red')

188 ms ± 26.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is can be done easily using `case when` if you have Pandas v2.2.0 (Jan 2024)

- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39154
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.2.0/whatsnew/v2.2.0.html#create-a-pandas-series-based-on-one-or-more-conditions

example from the release notes:

```
    import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[4, 5, 6]))

default=pd.Series('default', index=df.index)

default.case_when(
     caselist=[
         (df.a == 1, 'first'),                              # condition, replacement
         (df.a.gt(1) & df.b.eq(5), 'second'),  # condition, replacement
     ],
)

Out[4]: 
0      first
1     second
2    default
dtype: object
```