# How do I take a column of pandas data based on a scalar condition AND a column comparison?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a starting DataFrame:

```
ipdb> df[["line_amount","modifiedAmount"]]
   line_amount modifiedAmount
0        30.00               
1         2.88           2.88
2       199.20          199.2
3      -105.00           -104
4       150.00            150
5        75.00               
6      -450.00           -450
7        16.13          16.13
8        20.00               
9       111.99         111.99
```

What I want is a new column of data (or really to replace the modifiedAmount column with one) that contains "" in cases where the original modifiedAmount was EITHER:

- already ""   OR
- equal to line_amount

I'm having such trouble figuring out how to accomplish what I'd've expected to be very easy!

I can get this:

```
ipdb> equal_test = df.modifiedAmount == df.line_amount
ipdb> blank_test = df.modifiedAmount == ""
```

but I can't do this:

```
ipdb> blank_test and equal_test
*** ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714181/conditional-logic-on-pandas-dataframe) option when I want to apply a scalar result, but I couldn't figure out how to put df into lambda like this:

```
ipdb> df.modifiedAmount.apply(lambda x: "" if x == df.line_amount else x)
*** NameError: global name 'df' is not defined
```

Any ideas?

The desired result look like this:

```
ipdb> df[["line_amount","modifiedAmount"]]
   line_amount modifiedAmount
0        30.00               
1         2.88         
2       199.20         
3      -105.00         -104.00
4       150.00         
5        75.00               
6      -450.00         
7        16.13         
8        20.00               
9       111.99
```

(yes, ideally I want to cast any remaining values to a float to two decimal places)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `apply` column-wise on the whole dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Create some dummy data and put it in a dataframe. I used np.nan instead of "".

```
df =pd.DataFrame( { 'lineAmount':[30.00,2.88,199.20,-105.00,150.00,75.00,-450.00,16.13,20.00,111.99], \
                'modifiedAmount':[np.nan,2.88,199.20,-104.00,150.00,np.nan,-450.00,16.13,np.nan,111.99]})
```

Then you can use a lamda function of the whole dataframe, column-wise using the `axis=1` parameter of `apply()`:

```
df['modifiedAmount'] =df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x.modifiedAmount == x.lineAmount else x.modifiedAmount, axis =1)
```

output:

```
    lineAmount  modifiedAmount
0   30.00       NaN
1   2.88        NaN
2   199.20      NaN
3   -105.00     -104
4   150.00      NaN
5   75.00       NaN
6   -450.00     NaN
7   16.13       NaN
8   20.00       NaN
9   111.99      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Building the dataset. Note that i've entered all numbers as float (they seem to be strings in your code)

```
import pandas as pd
s_dict = {'line_amount': [30, 2.88, 199.2, -105, 150, 75, -450, 16.13, 20, 111.99], 'modifiedAmount': [None,2.88,199.2,-104, 150, None, -450, 16.13, None, 111.99]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(s_dict)
print df
```

output :

```
   line_amount  modifiedAmount
0        30.00             NaN
1         2.88            2.88
2       199.20          199.20
3      -105.00         -104.00
4       150.00          150.00
5        75.00             NaN
6      -450.00         -450.00
7        16.13           16.13
8        20.00             NaN
9       111.99          111.99
```

This line requires a bit of explanation. Here we are using boolean masks (`df.modifiedAmount == df.line_amount` and `pd.isnull(df.modifiedAmount)`), separated by a `|` (OR comparison), and the `~` at the beginning means NOT.

```
df['new_mod'] = df.loc[~((df.modifiedAmount == df.line_amount) | (pd.isnull(df.modifiedAmount))), 'modifiedAmount']
print df
```

output :

```
   line_amount  modifiedAmount  new_mod
0        30.00             NaN      NaN
1         2.88            2.88      NaN
2       199.20          199.20      NaN
3      -105.00         -104.00     -104
4       150.00          150.00      NaN
5        75.00             NaN      NaN
6      -450.00         -450.00      NaN
7        16.13           16.13      NaN
8        20.00             NaN      NaN
9       111.99          111.99      NaN
```