# How to check whether all values in a column satisfy a condition in Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I check if *all values* under `col1` satisfy a condition such as `> 2`?

```
import pandas as pd

d = [
    {'col1': 3, 'col2': 'wasteful'},
    {'col1': 0, 'col2': 'hardly'},
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I could go

```
if all(col1 > 2 for i, col1, col2 in df.itertuples()):
    #do stuff
```

but is there a *more readable*, faster and/or has less memory footprint way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Logic on Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714181/conditional-logic-on-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Can you be little more specific? There might be alot of better ways.

Comment: @GarbageCollector mostly readability wise but performance wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you need create boolean mask and then [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) for check if all `True`s:

```
print (df['col1'] > 2)
0     True
1    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool

print ((df['col1'] > 2).all())
False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to check if all column of a dataframe satisfies a condition

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = [
  {'col1': 3, 'col2': 'wasteful'},
  {'col1': 0, 'col2': 'hardly'},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(all(np.where(df['col1'] > 2, True, False)))
#False
```

Answer (score 0):

A further option is the application of lambda-Functions

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [{'col1': 3, 'col2': 'wasteful'},
    {'col1': 0, 'col2': 'hardly'},
    {'col1': 9, 'col2': 'stuff'}])

print(df['col1'].apply(lambda x: True if ((x>2) & (x<8)) else False))

#result:
#0 True
#1 False
#2 False
```